# Trying to link an activity from a listActivity

Tags: java, android

I have a list menu that links to another list menu and into an activity called counter. But the counter keeps throwing an exception and not show me the actual counter activity

here's the code below

```
package com.example.taekwondobuddy.util;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Tools extends ListActivity{

String classes[] = {"Counter","Accelermeter","Timer"} ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Tools.this,  android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.taekwondobuddy.util" + cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Tools.this, ourclass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
   }

     }
```

the tool class

```
package com.example.taekwondobuddy.util;

import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Tools extends ListActivity{

String classes[] = {"Counter","Accelermeter","Timer"} ;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(Tools.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, classes));
}


@Override
protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onListItemClick(l, v, position, id);
    String cheese = classes[position];
    try{
    Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.taekwondobuddy.util" + cheese);
    Intent ourIntent = new Intent(Tools.this, ourclass);
    startActivity(ourIntent);
    } catch(ClassNotFoundException e){
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
   }

  }
```

the counter class

```
package com.example.taekwondobuddy.util;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
```

public class Counter extends Activity {

```
int counter;
Button add;
Button sub;
TextView display;

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.counter);

    counter = 0;
    add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvDisplay);
    add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter++;
            display.setText("Counter: " + counter);
        }
    });
    sub.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter--;
            display.setText("Counter: " + counter);
        }
    });
   }

 }
```

and the counter.xml if that helps anyone

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >


<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:text="Counter: 0"
android:textSize="45dp"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:id="@+id/tvDisplay"

    ></TextView>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
    android:text="Add" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
    android:text="Subtract" />

 </RelativeLayout>
```

I can't see what can be wrong any ideas?

Comment: do you have the logcat for the exception thats thrown?

Comment: just try to print in logs what you are getting in "ourclass" variable

Comment: `  Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.taekwondobuddy.util" + cheese);` in this line append "." before cheese

Comment: @panini can't find it on the logcat but I'm pretty sure it's throwing an exception because the counter on the menu doesn't go anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Class ourclass = Class.forName("com.example.taekwondobuddy.util" + cheese);` in this line append "." before cheese